# Sequelize - How to verify an encrypted email that must be unique

Tags: sequelize.js

I encrypt the email of my users in the sequelize model which must be unique. I haven't found a way to do the uniqueness check because of the encryption.

Thanks for your help

```
User.findOrCreate({
  where: {
    encryptedEmail: "demo@demo.fr"
  },
  defaults: {
    encryptedEmail: "demo@demo.fr",
  }
})
```

Here is the encryption and decryption code that I use:

```
const crypto = require('../auth/crypto');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    encryptedEmail: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
    }
  });

  User.beforeCreate(async (user, options) => {
    console.log(`----> beforeCreate: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`)
    const { encryptedEmail } = user;
    console.log(`----> beforeCreate: ${encryptedEmail}`)
    user.encryptedEmail = await crypto.encrypt(encryptedEmail);
    console.log(`----> beforeCreate_02: ${user.encryptedEmail}`)
  });

  User.beforeUpdate(async (user, options) => {
    console.log(`----> beforeUpdate: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`)
    const { encryptedEmail } = user;    
    console.log(`----> beforeUpdate02: ${encryptedEmail}`)
    user.encryptedEmail = await crypto.encrypt(encryptedEmail);
  });

  User.beforeValidate(async (user, options) => {
    console.log(`----> beforeValidate: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`)
    const { encryptedEmail } = user
    console.log(`----> beforeValidate02: ${encryptedEmail}`)
    const emailExists = await User.findOne({
      where: { encryptedEmail },
    });
    if (emailExists) {
      throw new Error('Adresse e-mail déjà utilisée');
    }
  });

  return User;
};
```

Emails are well encrypted with crypto with a unique constraint (code above). During validation, it looks for the decrypted email but does not decrypt the stored email.

Comment: Uniqueness is verified by DB using a unique constraint and that means you need to store emails in DB as is to be able to check against emails for uniqueness.

Comment: Emails are well stored in database and encrypted with crypto

Comment: So emails in DB already encrypted?

Comment: In thos case you can try to create a unique constraint as well

Comment: Emails are well encrypted with crypto with a unique constraint (code above). During validation, it looks for the decrypted email but does not decrypt the stored email.

Comment: I updated the code in the question

Comment: Can you show the table schema in DB?

Comment: For the test the database only contains the id and encryptedEmail, constructor sequelize in the question

Comment: Thank you Anatoly, after a lot of modification and tests I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone here is what I managed to do.

**user.model.js**

```
const crypto = require('../auth/crypto');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: {
        msg: `L'email est utilisé ou incorrect`
      },
      validate: {
        notEmpty: {msg: `L'email ne peut être vide`},
        notNull: { msg: `L'email est une propriété requise`}
      },
    },
    roles: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: {msg: `Le mot de passe ne peut être vide`},
        notNull: { msg: `Le mot de passe est une propriété requise`}
      }
    },
    date: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    connexionDate: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    super: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    },
    syncronisationEp: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    rolesProfil: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    firstname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },

    fonction: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    identifiant: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    settings: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON
    }

  }
  )
}
```

**crypto.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()

const crypto = require('crypto');
const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
const initVector = Buffer.from(process.env.INITVECTORSTRING, 'hex');
const Securitykey = Buffer.from(process.env.SECURITYKEYSTRING, 'hex');

exports.encrypt = function(data) {
  try {
    // console.log(`ENCRYPT`)
    // Securitykey = crypto.randomBytes(32);
    // initVector = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    // console.log(Securitykey.toString('hex'));
    // console.log(initVector);

    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, Securitykey, initVector);
    let encryptedData = cipher.update(data, 'utf-8', 'hex');
    encryptedData += cipher.final('hex');

    return encryptedData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`ERREUR ENCRYPT: ${error}`)
  }
}

exports.decrypt = function(data) {
  try {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(
      algorithm,
      Securitykey,
      initVector
    );
    let decryptedData = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf-8');
    decryptedData += decipher.final('utf8');

    return decryptedData;
  } catch (error) {}
}
```

**For create user**

```
User.findOrCreate({
  where: {
    email: crypto.encrypt("demo@demo.fr")
  },
  defaults: {
    // email: crypto.encrypt("demo@demo.fr"),
    email: crypto.encrypt("demo@demo.fr"),
    password: 'mot_de_passe',
    roles: "USER"
  }
})
```

Thanks to Anatoly for trying to help me